# How can I make a HQL using Instant from java.time

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, hql, java-time

I am developing a small project using spring-jpa. I decided to use java.time to deal with date problems. Everything was working fine until I had to deal with HQL.

So I am trying to make this query:

```
@Query("SELECT sensor "
            + "FROM TrashSensor sensor "
            + "join sensor.measurementList measurement "
            + "WHERE sensor.id = 100 AND measurement.instantOfMeasure > '2017-01-01'")
    public TrashSensor findTrashSensorByIdCustom();
```

But the type of `measurement.instantOfMeasure` is a Instant from java.time.

So this last AND of my WHERE clause is always returning true so I don't get the filter I need.

**How can I make this comparison using HQL and java.time? Does Hibernate support this??**

Comment: Create an `Instant` object and pass it in as parameter perhaps ...

Answer (score 0):

You can develop it with

**1 way -> (in TrashSensorRepository interface )**

```
@Query("SELECT sensor "
            + "FROM TrashSensor sensor "
            + "join sensor.measurementList measurement "
            + "WHERE sensor.id =:sensorId AND measurement.instantOfMeasure > :instantOfMeasure")
public TrashSensor findTrashSensorByIdCustom(@Param("sensorId") sensorId, @Param("instantOfMeasure") Instant instantOfMeasure);
```

The types from the java.time package are directly mapped to corresponding SQL types(Since Java 8)

- LocalDate is mapped to DATE
- LocalTime and OffsetTime are mapped to TIME
- Instant, LocalDateTime, OffsetDateTime and ZonedDateTime are mapped to TIMESTAMP

**2 way -> (if you have created custom utility class for run HQL dynamically)**

```
// Utility for run custom dynamic HQL query
@Service
@Transactional
public class HibernateQueryService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateQueryService.class);
    private JpaContext jpaContext;

    public List executeHibernateQuery(String sql, Class entity){
        log.debug("HibernateQuery executing: "+sql);
        Session session = jpaContext.getEntityManagerByManagedType(Article.class).unwrap(Session.class);
        return session.createQuery(sql, entity).getResultList();
    }
}
// Custom converter
public class CustomConverter{    

public static Timestamp toTimestamp(Instant time){
        return time != null ? Timestamp.from(time) : null;
    }

    public static Instant toInstant(Timestamp timestamp){
        return timestamp != null ? timestamp.toInstant() : null;
    }

}
// Solution

public class Solution2{


    public static makeIt(){

        boolean isFirst = true;

        String query = "SELECT sensor "
            + "FROM TrashSensor sensor "
            + "join sensor.measurementList measurement ";            

        if(sensor.id != null){
            query += isFirst ? "WHERE " : "AND ";
            query += "sensor.id="+sensor.id+" ";
            isFirst = false;
        }

        if(measurement.instantOfMeasure != null){
            query += isFirst ? "WHERE " : "AND ";
            query += "measurement.instantOfMeasure > "+toTimestamp(measurement.instantOfMeasure)+" ";            
        }

        List<TrashSensor> hibernateQueryService.executeHibernateQuery(query, TrashSensor.class);

    }


}
```